# Button inside a triangle div

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS and HTML to make a 'triangle' div:

```css
.arrow-right {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 60px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
  border-left: 60px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-right">
  <p>next</p>
</div>
```

The problem is I want to have text (one word) inside the div (center of the triangle) but it breaks the triangle and put beside it.

Comment: the problem is your triangle div is only border. i.e. it has no width and height of its own. therefor you can't put data in it.

Comment: You will need to create some kind of `position: absolute` solution to take the text out of the normal document flow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this is by positioning the element relative to its original position

```css
.arrow-right {
  position: relative;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 60px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
  border-left: 60px solid green;
}

.arrow-right p{
   position: relative;
   left: -50px;
   top: -25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-right">
  <p>next</p>
</div>
```

Comment: exactly, seems like the most centered text of the examples provided, thank you

Answer (score 3):

```css
.arrow-right {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 60px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
  border-left: 60px solid green;
  position:relative;
}
.arrow-right p{
      position: absolute;
    top: -24px;
    left: -50px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="arrow-right">
  <p>next</p>
</div>
```

Do you want this output?

Answer (score 1):

You can put only this css in p tag:

```css
.arrow-right {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 60px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
  border-left: 60px solid green;
}
.arrow-right p {
  left: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-right">
  <p>next</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this below code...

```css
.arrow-right {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 60px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
  border-left: 60px solid green;
}

.arrow-right p{
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-right">
  <p> next </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.arrow-right {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 60px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
  border-left: 60px solid green;
}

.arrow-right p {
  position: relative;
  left: -48px;
  top: -26px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-right">
  <p>next</p>
</div>
```

Otherwise you can do like this. Add `position:relative` css rule to `.arrow-right` then write css rules for '`.arrow-right p`' as `position:absolute;left: 15px;top: 40px;`